# ¿Como obtener el valor seleccionado en jQuery Dropdown?

Tags: jquery

Estoy utilizando este plugin para animar un Dropdown:

https://dane.one/projects/jquery-dropdown/docs/

tipo select pero con listas del tipo:

```
<ul id="ul_prueba" data-dropdown='{ "closeReset": false }'>
    <li>Option 1</li>
    <li>Option 2</li>
    <li>Option 3                    
        <ul>
            <li>Option 3.1</li>
            <li>Option 3.2</li>
            <li>Option 3.3
               <ul>
                  <li>Option 3.3.1</li>
                  <li>Option 3.3.2</li>
                  <li>Option 3.3.3</li>
               </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>                       
</ul>
```

Lo que necesito es obtener el valor seleccionado al enviar el formulario. ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?.

Comment: Ojo, son listas con elementos anidados, debes especificar si los sub-elementos (2.1, 2.2, 2.3) entran también en la intención de *obtener el valor seleccionado*.  Por cierto, es una lista *incoherente*  ¿cómo es que el `2.1` es parte dependiente del `1.3`
?  ¿ ... ?

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta Cedano. Si, todos los elementos entran en la intencion de obtener el valor seleccionado. En cuanto a la coherencia, es solo un ejemplo a los efectos de mostrar como es la lista, de todas formas lo modifico. Gracias

Comment: cuando seleccionas una opcíon se agrega alguna clase ?

Answer (score 3):

Puedes hacerlo así:

- Creas un selector que abarque todos los `li` dentro del `ul` con id `ul_prueba`, valiéndote para ello de `querySelectorAll`
- Asignas un `click` listener a todos esos elementos con el `forEach`
- Con la ayuda de `firstChild` y de `nodeValue` obtienes solamente el valor del primer hijo del elemento, eso debido a que de lo contrario en casos como `Option 3` te traerá el valor de ese `li` y del `ul` anidado con todos sus sub li.
- Se usará también `trim()` para eliminar posibles espacios o saltos de línea sobrantes.
- Tendrás finalmente en la variable `liText` el dato, para poder usarlo o pasarlo a donde necesites.

```js
var allLi = document.querySelectorAll('#ul_prueba>li');
allLi.forEach(function(item) {
  item.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        var liText=e.target.firstChild.nodeValue.trim();
        console.log(liText);
  });
});
```

```html
<ul id="ul_prueba">
  <li>Option 1</li>
  <li>Option 2</li>
  <li>Option 3
    <ul>
      <li>Option 3.1</li>
      <li>Option 3.2</li>
      <li>Option 3.3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda Cedano, como seria para poder encontrar el valor seleccionado al querer enviar el formulario?. Ahi modifique la pregunta. Gracias!

Comment: @Patricio podrias agregar un input hiden y en vez de dar el `alert()` pones tipo `$("#seleccion").val(e.target.innerHTML);` asi le pones un valor al input y lo podes enviar tramite el submit del form

Comment: @Patricio la respuesta responde a tu planteamiento original. En cuanto a enviarlo *el valor seleccionado al enviar el formulario*, eso no es posible con listas `ul ... li`, ya que los mismos son valores fijos, no tienen ningún indicador de selección. Para eso necesitarás usar sea `radiobutton`, `checkbox`, `select` o algo así, donde es posible seleccionar uno entre varios valores. Las listas no son para eso. De todos modos, creo que deberías plantear esa duda en otra pregunta, revisando primero entre las preguntas del sitio, porque eso seguro que ha sido respondido ya aquí.

Comment: Gracias Cedano, estoy intentando solucionarlo como lo sugirio Federico en el comentarios anterior. Gracias!

Comment: @Patricio pero si estás creando tu propio código es mejor que uses los elementos que existen para las cosas que quieres hacer, en vez de recurrir a procedimientos extraños. A no ser que obligatoriamente necesites un `li`.  En ese caso se puede hacer de otras formas, aunque en vez de crear más elementos adicionales yo usaría otras cosas como los atributos `data`. O una etiqueta interna `value`  o `id`  que iría dentro del mismo `li`  y que cambiaría según el mismo sea clickeado o no. De todos modos, dado que no es un elemento para eso, te verás en la dificultad de manejar el marcado/desmarcado.

Answer (score 1):

Es cierto que el plugin puedes pasarle un tag `ul` y te armara un dropdown, pero para que complicarse si el plugin también te permite pasarle un `select option` y también te armara un dropdown, con la ventaja que tu `select option` quedara oculto y cada vez que cambies de valor automáticamente se cambia el `select`. Al final puedes obtener tu valor pegándole al id del select option.

Te dejo dos ejemplos, no se cual de los te guste más.

El dropdown con el grupo 3 no anidado:

```
<select id="ul_prueba" data-dropdown='{ "nested": false, "closeReset": false }'>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <optgroup label="Group 3">
        <option>Option 3.1</option>
        <option>Option 3.2</option>
        <option>Option 3.3</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

El dropdown con el grupo 3 anidado:

```
<select id="ul_prueba" data-dropdown='{ "nested": true, "closeReset": false }'>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <optgroup label="Group 3">
        <option>Option 3.1</option>
        <option>Option 3.2</option>
        <option>Option 3.3</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Inicializas tu select option con `$('#ul_prueba').dropdown();`

Y para obtener el valor con `$('#ul_prueba').val();`

Como puedes ver de esta forma es mucho mas sencillo de obtener el valor del dropdown.

## Actualizando

Una forma de utilizar grupos dentro de grupos es la siguiente:

```
<ul id="ul_prueba" data-dropdown='{ "closeReset": false }'>
    <li>Option 1</li>
    <li>Option 2</li>
    <li>Option 3
        <ul>
            <li>Option 3.1</li>
            <li>Option 3.2</li>
            <li>Option 3.3
               <ul>
                  <li>Option 3.3.1</li>
                  <li>Option 3.3.2</li>
                  <li>Option 3.3.3</li>
               </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Si en tal caso necesitas que el valor sea distinto al texto que muestras debes de agregar el siguiente atributo `data-dropdown-value` a cada una de las opciones.

```
<ul id="ul_prueba" data-dropdown='{ "closeReset": false }'>
    <li data-dropdown-value="1">Option 1</li>
    <li data-dropdown-value="2">Option 2</li>
    <li>Option 3
        <ul>
            <li data-dropdown-value="3.1">Option 3.1</li>
            <li data-dropdown-value="3.2">Option 3.2</li>
            <li>Option 3.3
               <ul>
                  <li data-dropdown-value="3.3.1">Option 3.3.1</li>
                  <li data-dropdown-value="3.3.1">Option 3.3.2</li>
                  <li data-dropdown-value="3.3.1">Option 3.3.3</li>
               </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

De esta forma (como ya no existe los select option) ya no se podrá seleccionar la información como si de un `select option` se tratara si no que, se utilizara la función `value` del propio plugins.

Para inicializar:  `$('#ul_prueba').dropdown();`

Para obtener el valor hay dos formas:

***Forma 1***: `$("#ul_prueba").dropdown("value");`

***Forma 2***: `$("#ul_prueba").data("plugin.dropdown").value();`

De las dos formas debería de funcionar, pero en algunas versiones la ***forma 1*** a veces se queda colgada, Te recomiendo probar las dos.

Comment: Gracias Orlando por tu respuesta, es cierto lo que dices y mucho mas conveniente, el inconveniente es que tengo anidado 2 niveles y ahi deja de funcionar como quiero. Eh probado con tu ejemplo anidando 2 niveles pero no funciona como deseo. Sabes si se puede hacer?. Gracias!

Comment: @Patricio e actualizado la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Así:

```
var valor = $('#nombreselect option').val();
```

Comment: este codigo funciona solo para `<select>` no creo que sea eficaz con las listas

Comment: Gracias por su respuesta. Si, la respuesta solo funciona con los select. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar this para obtener el elemento actual después de que se le haga click. 
En el caso de que cada Li tenga un id podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
$(function(){ 
   $('ul li').click(function(e) 
   { 
       console.log('Seleccionaste el elemento con id: ' + this.id);
   // Aquí van tus instrucciones... 
   });
});
```

Comment: Gracias por su respuesta, en realidad el dropdown lo tengo en un formulario, es decir que necesito el valor al enviar el formulario. Gracias!

Comment: Estas usando php?. Por favor edita el código, solo nos muestras el ul y si estas trabajando con php o ajax seria bueno saber como esta estructurado.

Comment: Sisi, y jQuery.

Answer (score -1):

Puedes hacerlo asi:

```js
// seleccionamos todos los li que esten dentro de un ul y hacemos un loop
for(el of document.querySelectorAll("ul li")){
     // le asignamos un evento click a cada 1
     el.addEventListener("click",(e) =>{
     // recibimos el evento y paramos su propagacion a otros elementos
     e.stopPropagation();
    // seleccionamos el evento clickeado lo dividimos hasta que empieze el siguiente ul obetenemos el primer elemento
 // y usamos la funcion trim() para eliminar los espacion
     console.log(e.target.innerHTML.split("<ul>")[0].trim());
   })
}
```

```html
<ul id="ul_prueba">
  <li>Option 1</li>
  <li>Option 2</li>
  <li>Option 3
    <ul>
      <li>Option 3.1
         <ul>
              <li>Option 3.1.1</li>
              <li>Option 3.1.2</li>
              <li>Option 3.1.3</li>
           </ul>
         </li>
      <li>Option 3.2</li>
      <li>Option 3.3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hola Bryro, las publicaciones que son básicamente código se consideran de baja calidad. Deberías editar tu respuesta para añadir algo más de detalle: ¿qué es lo que has cambiado? ¿por qué esos cambios solucionan el problema? Lee [answer] para más información.

Comment: ok vale! ..............